# what's the order if there are two asyncio.get_event_loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There are two things need to be done: host website and send notification.So I use the following ways to solve this problems:

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio


async def _send_proactive_message():
    ...

async def pre_init():
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    await _send_proactive_message()

APP = web.Application()
APP.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
APP.router.add_get("/api/notify", notify)




if __name__ == '__main__':


    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        event_loop.create_task(pre_init())
        web.run_app(APP, host="localhost", port=CONFIG.PORT)

    finally:
        event_loop.close()
```

Because there is one event_loop in web.run_app, I don't understand which one run first and how to control every event_loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your way to create a task before starting event loop is ok, but only if `run_app` won't set and use another event loop.

Better way is to create tasks or other async objects once event loop is started. This way you will make sure created objects are attached to an active running event loop.

The best way to do it in your case is to use [on_startup](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application.on_startup) hook:

```
async def pre_init(app):
    await _send_proactive_message()


async def make_app():
    app = web.Application()

    app.router.add_post("/api/messages", messages)
    app.router.add_get("/api/notify", notify)

    app.on_startup.append(pre_init)

    return app


web.run_app(make_app())
```

Comment: in this way, I will send message first then I can open website. In my way I can open website and send message at the same time. If I add await asyncio.sleep(20) in pre_init function I can control when to send message after open website. But in your way I must wait 20 seconds then open website

Comment: I tried, same result. Maybe I didn't speak my mind clearly

Comment: Maybe the OP wants `asyncio.create_task(_send_proactive_message)` in `pre_init` instead of `await ...`?

Comment: maybe all this due to my python version is 3.6?